# How to remove element from array class

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, iterator

i have array declaration

```
array<int, 5> niz;
```

Now i need to found maximum in that array and to remove it . How to achieve that with class array?

**EDIT**

so array size cant be modified, so can i swift two elements in array then?

Comment: This is impossible. The array size is constant.

Answer (score 4):

It cannot be done. A `std::array` has a fixed, compile-time determined number of elements. If you want a container that supports a changing number of elements, you can use for example [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Is it possible to change , for example , first and second element of array then?

Comment: @AndroidBeginner try it yourself. It is very useful in learning.

Comment: @AndroidBegginer You mean to swap them? See [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot remove an element from an array, you can move (by swapping) the max element to the end of the array and keep a dynamic size.

```
const unsigned int fixed_size=5;
unsigned int dynamic_size = fixed_size;
std::array<int, fixed_size> myArray;
```

And when you find the max (will let you implement this part), swap it with the last index within the dynamic range.  And decrement the dynamic size.

```
std::swap( myArray[dynamic_size-1], myArray[max_index] );
--dynamic_size;
```

And this will iterate over the array, excluding the max element.

```
for( unsigned int i=0; i<dynamic_size; ++i ) printf( "%u: %d\n", i, myArray[i] );
```